# Bind TreeView Item header to a WrapPanel's selected child's content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a `TreeView` inside which there is one `TreeViewItem`. I also have a `WrapPanel` whose children are a bunch of `RadioButtons` added to and removed from the WrapPanel at runtime. Now what I want to achieve is when a RadioButton is checked (selected) in the WrapPanel, the checked RadioButton's content text should be displayed in the header of the TreeViewItem. I mean I want to bind the header property of the TreeViewItem to the selected RadioButton's content property. How do I do this preferably in xaml or else in code-behind?

Remember: The RadioButtons are added and removed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Using mvvm is the surest way. But if you need something simpler then when creating a RadioButton, assign the TreeViewItem to its Tag property. Further, when selecting a specific RadioButton:

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as RadioButton).Tag as TreeViewItem).Header = (sender as RadioButton).Content;
}
```